# Dynamically building a table for a report

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, reporting

I have a temporary table that hold all items available

```
#TableA

ItemId  ItemName    ItemVer
1       Name1       2
2       Name2       9
3       Name3       5
.
.
.
500     Name500     3
```

I then have another that holds all the dates a Snapshot was taken along with the SnapshotId

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpSnapshot_Dates(
[SnapshotId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[DateTaken] datetime NOT NULL) 

INSERT INTO #tmpSnapshot_Dates SELECT SnapshotId, DateTaken From Snapshot_Info Where DateTaken <= @EndDate
```

Now for each date in the `#tmpSnapshot_Dates` table I want to get a count that relates it each Item

```
SELECT ItemId, Count(*) From Items Where SnapshotId = @SnapshotId
```

And then update `#TableA` by adding a column

```
DECLARE @ColName VARCHAR(100)
SET @ColName = 'Installed ' + CONVERT(Varchar, @DateA, 6)

exec('ALTER TABLE #TableA ADD ['+@ColName+']  int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_#TableA_Installed on] DEFAULT 0')
```

And then insert the data into the new column.  I then need to repeat this for each date in `#tmpSnapshot_Dates`

giving a resulting `#TableA` that looks something like

```
#TableA

ItemId  ItemName    ItemVer    Installed 01 Jan 12    Installed 07 Feb 12 
1       Name1       2          34                     33
2       Name2       9          56                     59
3       Name3       5          12                     26
.
.
.
500     Name500     3          98                     106
```

My questions are

1. Am I creating a nightmare here by approaching it the wrong way?
2. How am I best to loop through `#tmpSnapshot_Dates` and then get the data to create the next column? I always try to avoid cursors but is this one of those situation I need to use one?

There could be 12 columns to add and not every item will be returned for each date.

Comment: I don't know why the format of this post has ended up in long lines.  It doesn't look like this when I edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely it won't be nice, but yes, you need to use cursors and iterate over the `#tmpSnapshot_Dates`, but if you have the option i suggest you to use a reporting software with the capability to create pivot grids.

Comment: I cant use any other reporting software bar the one I have. I have used cursors and its not as bad as it it could be.  With a max of 12 dates it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be better to have a separate (temp?) table referencing the `ItemId` in `#TableA` eg:

```
InstalledDate    ItemId    Count
-------------    ------    -----
2012-01-01            1       34
2012-01-01            2       56
2012-01-01            3       12
.                     .        .
.                     .        .
.                     .        .
2012-01-01          500       98
2012-02-07            1       33
2012-02-07            2       59
2012-02-07            3       26
.                     .        .
.                     .        .
.                     .        .
2012-02-07          500      106
```